# Chroot Postgresql Error

Tags: postgresql

Currently I'm trying to create the first PostgreSQL 9.5 cluster on Linux deploy android 5.0.2, and it seems to be a shared memory error.

```
FATAL: could not create shared memory segment: Function not implemented
Detail: Failed system call was shmget(key=1, size=40, 03600).
child process exited with exit code 1
initdb removing contents of data directory "/var/lib/postgresql/9.5/main"
Error: initdb failed
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

Android doesn't support POSIX or System V shared memory. [It has its own non-standard API, ashmem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17510157/398670).

PostgreSQL does not support ashmem. To make the PostgreSQL server run on Android I expect you'd need to either use a custom kernel that does support either POSIX or System V shared memory, or add support for ashmem to PostgreSQL.

There's [a also wrapper tool, android-shmem](https://github.com/pelya/android-shmem) that emulates System V shared memory using ashmem transparently either by direct linking or `LD_PRELOAD`. You could try that.